# I want to understand why lapply exhausts memory but a for loop doesn't

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I am working in R and trying to understand the best way to join data frames when one of them is very large.

I have a data frame which is not excruciatingly large but also not small (~80K observations of 8 variables, 144 MB).  I need to match observations from this data frame to observations from another smaller data frame on the basis of a date range.  Specifically, I have:

```
events.df <- data.frame(individual=c('A','B','C','A','B','C'),
                     event=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                     time=as.POSIXct(c('2014-01-01 08:00:00','2014-01-05 13:00:00','2014-01-10 07:00:00','2014-05-01 01:00:00','2014-06-01 12:00:00','2014-08-01 10:00:00'),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

trips.df <- data.frame(individual=c('A','B','C'),trip=c('x1A','CA1B','XX78'),
                    trip_start = as.POSIXct(c('2014-01-01 06:00:00','2014-01-04 03:00:00','2014-01-08 12:00:00'),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                    trip_end=as.POSIXct(c('2014-01-03 06:00:00','2014-01-06 03:00:00','2014-01-11 12:00:00'),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

In my case *events.df* contains around 80,000 unique events and I am looking to match them to events from the *trips.df* data frame, which has around 200 unique trips. Each trip has a unique trip identifier ('trip'). I would like to match based on whether the event took place during the date range defining a trip.

First, I have tried *fuzzy_inner_join* from the *fuzzyjoin* library.  It works great in principal:

```
fuzzy_inner_join(events.df,trips.df,by=c('individual'='individual','time'='trip_start','time'='trip_end'),match_fun=list(`==`,`>=`,`<=`))
   individual.x event                time individual.y trip          trip_start            trip_end
1            A     1 2014-01-01 08:00:00            A  x1A 2014-01-01 06:00:00 2014-01-03 06:00:00
2            B     1 2014-01-05 13:00:00            B CA1B 2014-01-04 03:00:00 2014-01-06 03:00:00
3            C     1 2014-01-10 07:00:00            C XX78 2014-01-08 12:00:00 2014-01-11 12:00:00
>
```

but runs out of memory when I try to apply it to the larger data frames.

Here is a second solution I cobbled together:

```
trip.match <- function(tripid){
   individual <- trips.df$individual[trips$trip==tripid]
   start <- trips.df$trip_start[trips$trip==tripid]
   end <- trips.df$trip_end[trips$trip==tripid]

tmp <- events.df[events.df$individual==individual &
                 events.df$time>= start &
                 events.df$time<= end,]
tmp$trip <- tripid
return(tmp) 
}

result <- data.frame(rbindlist(lapply(unique(trips.df$trip),trip.match)
```

This solution also breaks down because the list object returned by lapply is 25GB and the attempt to cast this list to a data frame also exhausts the available memory.

I have been able to do what I need to do using a for loop.  Basically, I append a column onto *events.df* and loop through the unique trip identifiers and populate the new column in *events.df* accordingly:

```
events.df$trip <- NA
for(i in unique(trips.df$trip)){
  individual <- trips.df$individual[trips.df$trip==i]
  start <- min(trips.df$trip_start[trips.df$trip==i])
  end <- max(trips.df$trip_end[trips.df$trip==i])  

  events.df$trip[events.df$individual==individual & events.df$time >= start & events.df$time <= end] <- i
}

> events.df
  individual event                time trip
1          A     1 2014-01-01 08:00:00  x1A
2          B     1 2014-01-05 13:00:00 CA1B
3          C     1 2014-01-10 07:00:00 XX78
4          A     2 2014-05-01 01:00:00 <NA>
5          B     2 2014-06-01 12:00:00 <NA>
6          C     2 2014-08-01 10:00:00 <NA>
```

My question is this: I'm not a very advanced R programmer so I expect there is a more memory efficient way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.  Is there?

Comment: @Parfait, in the 3rd code chunk above you'll see ```result <- data.frame(rbindlist(lapply(unique(trips.df$trip),trip.match)```...the lapply() is wrapped inside some code to cast the resulting list to a data frame.

Comment: Your fuzzjoin does not use `tripid`.

Comment: @Parfait, yes, the fuzzy join does not join on the tripid.  The idea is to attach the tripid to each event.  The fuzzy join works on the individual and the time range to attach the tripid to the row for any corresponding event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a table that expands the trip ranges by hour and then merge with the event. Here is an example (using the `data.table` function because `data.table` outperforms `data.frame` for larger datasets):

```
library('data.table')
tripsV <- unique(trips.df$trip)
tripExpand <- function(t){
  dateV <- seq(trips.df$trip_start[trips.df$trip == t], 
               trips.df$trip_end[trips.df$trip == t], 
               by = 'hour')
  data.table(trip = t, time = dateV)
}

trips.dt <- rbindlist(
  lapply(tripsV, function(t) tripExpand(t))
  )

merge(events.df,
      trips.dt,
      by = 'time')
```

Output:

```
                 time individual event trip
1 2014-01-01 08:00:00          A     1  x1A
2 2014-01-05 13:00:00          B     1 CA1B
3 2014-01-10 07:00:00          C     1 XX78
```

So you are basically translating the trip table to trip-hour long-form panel dataset. That makes for easy merging with the event dataset. I haven't benchmarked it to your current method but my hunch is that it will be more memory & cpu efficient.

Comment: thanks, your solution works well for the case that I posted.  I didn't do a great job of expressing the general nature of my problem.  Your solution does break down if I have an event occurring at say ```2014-01-01 08:31:00```.  In that case, I can use your framework and just expand the trips data set by minute.  In practice this is exactly what I have done and I can confirm that expanding the trips data set and merging with data.table() is substantially faster than using ```fuzzy_inner_join()```.

Comment: Great-- I'm happy it worked! As far as the minute observations go, glad that you figured out a work-around; another solution would be to round the event times to the hour prior to the merge with `trunc.POSIXt(time, 'hours')`

Answer (score 1):

Consider splitting your data with data.table's `split` and run each subset on `fuzzy_inner_join` then call `rbindlist` to bind all data frame elements together for single output.

```
df_list <- data.table::split(events.df, by="individual")

fuzzy_list <- lapply(df_list, function(sub.df) {
      fuzzy_inner_join(sub.df, trips.df, 
                       by = c('individual'='individual', 'time'='trip_start', 'time'='trip_end'), 
                       match_fun = list(`==`,`>=`,`<=`)
      )
})

# REMOVE TEMP OBJECT AND CALL GARBAGE COLLECTOR
rm(df_list); gc()

final_df <- rbindlist(fuzzy_list)

# REMOVE TEMP OBJECT AND CALL GARBAGE COLLECTOR
rm(fuzzy_list); gc()
```

Comment: thanks.  I have tried implementing a segmented approach as you suggested.  Informally, I've found that the fuzzy join works very slowly even on data frames including ~10K events.  Splitting the data will eventually get me what I need...but I guess I was looking for something faster.  At any rate, your suggestion is valuable so I upvoted your answer.  The answer provided by Andrew Royal is a bit more direct and faster so I'm accepting that one.